# I cannot print the user input from my arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am not quite familiar of the array list.
If i run the program i was able to type all the variables but when i want to view what i wrote it does not print

```
import java.util.*;

public class Dynamic{
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int age;
    private String course;
    private int idnum;

    public Dynamic(String Fname, String Lname, int Age, String Course, int IdNum) {
        fname = Fname;
        lname = Lname;
        age = Age;
        course = Course;
        idnum = IdNum;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fname;   
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public int getidNum() {
        return idnum;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return fname+" "+lname+"  "+age+"    "+course+"    "+idnum;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        menu();
    }//end of main
    public static void menu() {
        ArrayList<Dynamic> users = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("1: Add Student\n2: View Student");
        int choose = in.nextInt();
        switch(choose) {
        case 1:
            addStudent(users);
            break;
        case 2:
            viewStudent(users);
            break;
        }   
    }//end of menu
```

This is my method for acquiring user input

```
    public static void addStudent(ArrayList<Dynamic> users) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Enter Name of Student");
        String Fname = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name of Student");
        String Lname= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Age of Student");
        int Age= in.nextInt();
        String trash = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Course of Student");
        String Course= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Id Number of Student");
        int IdNum = in.nextInt();
        Dynamic student = new Dynamic(Fname, Lname, Age, Course, IdNum);
        users.add(student);
        menu();
    }//end of add users
```

below is my viewStudent method i dont know whats wrong or missing. Im also a beginner i cant fully undersand arraylist method

```
    public static void viewStudent(ArrayList<Dynamic> users) {
        System.out.printf("%10s%7s%8s%10s\n", "Name","Age","Course","IdNumber");
        for (Dynamic stud : users)
        {
            System.out.println(stud);
        }   

    }//end of viewusers
}//end of studentclass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare ArrayList as a Global variable and then can use it anywhere Like this:-

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dynamic
{
    static ArrayList<Dynamic> users = new ArrayList<Dynamic>();
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int age;
    private String course;
    private int idnum;
    public Dynamic(String Fname, String Lname, int Age, String Course, int IdNum)
    {
        fname = Fname;
        lname = Lname;
        age = Age;
        course = Course;
        idnum = IdNum;
    } 
    public String getfName()
    {
        return fname;   
    }
    public String getlName()
    {
        return lname;
    } 
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    public String getCourse()
    {
        return course;
    }
    public int getidNum()
    {
        return idnum;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return fname+" "+lname+"  "+age+"    "+course+"    "+idnum;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
        menu();
    }//end of main
    public static void menu()
    {        
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("1: Add Student\n2: View Student");
        int choose = in.nextInt();
        switch(choose) {
            case 1:
                addStudent();
                break;
            case 2:
                viewStudent();
                break;
            }   
     }
    public static void addStudent()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please Enter Name of Student");
        String Fname = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name of Student");
        String Lname= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Age of Student");
        int Age= in.nextInt();
        String trash = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Course of Student");
        String Course= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please Enter Id Number of Student");
        int IdNum = in.nextInt();
        Dynamic student = new Dynamic(Fname, Lname, Age, Course, IdNum);
        users.add(student);
        menu();
    }//end of add users
    public static void viewStudent()
    {
        System.out.printf("%10s%7s%8s%10s\n", "Name","Age","Course","IdNumber");
        for (Dynamic stud : users)
        {
            System.out.println(stud);
        }   
    }//end of viewusers
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks working now but is there a different between static ArrayList<Dynamic> users = new ArrayList<Dynamic>(); and static ArrayList<Dynamic> users = new ArrayList<without a dynamic>();

Comment: @GameChanger `Dynamic` is a POJO class and you have a static instance of a container object of the same type. This is dangerous as this can prevent objects from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to `ArrayList` at all because all you are doing is `add` and iterate through it and there is nothing wrong with it. Now, what you should **NEVER** do is what has been suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59015007/6601614) which is to make a `static` `ArrayList` instance in your POJO class as in a long running application where  you are doing this in many places, it will prevent garbage collection of objects and this your heap will get used up unnecessarily.

A good practice for you will be to separate the organize your code into different layers (each layer is a class or a bunch of classes).
Here is what you can do:

Have a Data Input/Output Layer where you are reading only the data (From what I can guess, your input is based on entering a particular type of input per line and as such, it would be best to use a `BufferedReader` and read line by line and parse into the format that you want to).

Have a data processing layer where you apply whatever logic you want to on the data and process it.

Have a Data Repository layer (in your case you are using an `ArrayList` but put in into a separate class to simulate a database)

Have a data representation layer (which you already have, the POJO).

Here is how you can do it:
The repository:

```
public class DynamicRepository {
    private final ArrayList<Dynamic> dynamicArrayList;

    DynamicRepository(ArrayList<Dynamic> dynamicArrayList) {
        this.dynamicArrayList = dynamicArrayList;
    }

    public void add(Dynamic dynamic) {
        dynamicArrayList.add(dynamic);
    }

    public ArrayList<Dynamic> getDynamicArrayList() {
        return dynamicArrayList;
    }
}
```

The data processing class (in your case it does nothing but get and put data from and to the repository):

```
public class DynamicDaoImpl {
    private final DynamicRepository dr;

    DynamicDaoImpl(DynamicRepository dr) {
        this.dr = dr;
    }

    public void insertIntoRepository (String name, int age) {
        dr.add(new Dynamic(name, age));
    }

    public List<Dynamic> getAllFromRepository() {
        return dr.getDynamicArrayList();
    }
}
```

The Data input and output class that is responsible for getting your and outputting your data (this is usually the controller class):

```
public class DataInputOutputClass {
    private final BufferedReader br;
    private final DynamicDaoImpl daoImpl;

    DataInputOutputClass(BufferedReader br, DynamicDaoImpl daoImpl) {
        this.br = br;
        this.daoImpl = daoImpl;
    }

    void insertData() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter Name");
        String name = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Age");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        daoImpl.insertIntoRepository(name, age);
    }

    void printData() {
        for (Dynamic dynamic : daoImpl.getAllFromRepository()) {
            System.out.println(dynamic);
        }
    }
}
```

Your Driver class that puts everything in together:

```
 public class Driver {
        private final BufferedReader br;
        private final DataInputOutputClass dio;

        Driver(BufferedReader br, DataInputOutputClass dio) {
            this.br = br;
            this.dio = dio;
        }

        public void run() throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Enter Choice: 1 or 2");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            switch (choice) {
                case 1: {
                    dio.insertData();
                    run();
                    break;
                }

                case 2: {
                    dio.printData();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now create a totally separate class with only the main method like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DynamicDaoImpl dynamicDao = new DynamicDaoImpl(new DynamicRepository(new ArrayList<>()));
        DataInputOutputClass dataInputOutputClass = new DataInputOutputClass(br, dynamicDao);
        Driver dr = new Driver(br, dataInputOutputClass);

        dr.run();
    }
}
```

What you have now is a a code that is organized, easier to unit test and maintain and can be extended a lot more easily than what you initially had.